# Magento 2 Module Development - Code changes only work after VM reboot

Tags: magento, module, magento2

I created a small module and it works great.
But if I then make changes to the code, they only take effect after I restart the VM.
There must be an easier/faster way?!
It's not a big or error-prone change either.
I'm writing something to the log file and want to write another line underneath it.

This is working:

```
$this->logger->info("1: observer working");
```

This isnt working until reboot:

```
$this->logger->info("2: observer after");
```